# Laravel 5.8: $bal->balance is getting null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to get a value of `balance` column from a pivot table called `user_wallet` which goes like this:

[image]

So I wrote this at the Controller:

```
$bal = Wallet::with("users")->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($wallet_id, $user_id) {
    $query->where('wallet_id', $wallet_id);
    $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
})->first();
```

But when I do `dd($bal->balance)`, I get `null`!

So why is that? How can I get the `balance` value based on `user_id` and `wallet_id` properly?

Here is also the relationships between `User` model and `Wallet` model:

##### `User.php`

```
public function wallets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Wallet::class, 'user_wallet', 'user_id', 'wallet_id')->withPivot('balance');
}
```

##### `Wallet.php`

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_wallet', 'wallet_id', 'user_id');
}
```

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

Comment: try dd($bal->pivot->balance)

Comment: @JohnLobo `#message: "Trying to get property 'pivot' of non-object"`

Comment: you have to loop users to get pivot data  $bal->balance only possible DB query as  mentioned below answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is supposed to be like below. Becuase the relation you're making is with users table not user_wallet.

```
$bal = Wallet::with("users")
    ->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
        $query->where('id',$user_id);
    })
    ->where('id', $wallet_id)
    ->first();
```

You can make a simple query as well:

```
$bal = DB::table('user_wallet')
    ->where('wallet_id', $wallet_id)
    ->where('user_id', $user_id)
    ->first();

if (!empty($bal)) {
    $balance = $bal->balance;
}
```

Comment: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'wallet_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `wallets` where exists (select * from `users` inner join `user_wallet` on `users`.`usr_id` = `user_wallet`.`user_id` where `wallets`.`id` = `user_wallet`.`wallet_id` and `id` = 373) and `wallet_id` = 2 limit 1)`

Comment: it will be `id` not walled id.

Comment: Now I get `Trying to get property 'balance' of non-object`

Comment: it is becuase of the relation is belongstomany. and you're supposed to get many users with one wallet. you need to debug `$bal` and check what response are you getting.

Comment: How to debug `$bal`, where to start ?

Comment: Thank u mate. So the Eloquent won't work in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a many to many relationship, for getting the pivot table you loop like below:

```
@foreach($bal as $key => $value)
    {{$value->pivot->balance}}
@endforeach
```

or if it is a single item then you can do like:

```
$user = $bal->users()->first();

$user->pivot->balance;
```

or

```
$user = $bal->users->first();

$user->pivot->balance;
```

if still need directly then, as suggested by [@Dilip Hirapara answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68426321/1998801).

Comment: So the relationships that are shown in the question are correct ?

Comment: @cerealikaeme yes  relationship defined correct. try it this since you have data .if any error in this then let me know

Comment: Call to a member function users() on null

Comment: @cerealikaeme look like $bal is null it means no such record which you searched for

Comment: @cerealikaeme always use dd($bal->toArray()) what you have in collection so you can easily degug whats going wrong in it